# Longtable - Caption too short

Tags: captions, longtable

I'm using longtable. But the caption is too short that it splits up my 12 word caption into two lines centered, only 1/3 of the table width.

I would like to show the caption in one line. Any advice?
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTleft{-40pt}           
\setlength\LTright{-40pt}           
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllllllll@{}}
\caption{Why My Caption is Squeezed Here Can I Make The Length Longer?}\\
\hline\hline
Short Name & Full Name  & Source                                     \\
\hline
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @hooy. I just tried but it gave me error "LaTeX Error: \caption outside float." Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
```

to your code, right after (or before) setting `\LTleft` and `\LTright`.

Background: As opposite to the regular `\caption` the one from `longtable` is limited to the width `\LTcapwidth`. When using in portrait mode, the default value is quite reasonable, but too short in landscape mode.

Complete example document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTleft{-40pt}    
\setlength\LTright{-40pt}           
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllllllll@{}}
\caption{Why My Caption is Squeezed Here Can I Make The Length Longer?}\\
\hline\hline
Short Name & Full Name  & Source                                     \\
\hline
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Shameless self-advertisement: Adding `\usepackage{caption}` would have solved the issue, too, since it ignores `\LTcapwidth` (unless set to a specific value).

Comment: It appears `caption` also ignores `LTleft`, so the caption no longer aligns with the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\caption` package and add the following line into your preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont,singlelinecheck=on,justification=raggedright}
```